# nodejs mysql handleDisconnect get "ECONNREFUSED" it happens inconsistently

Tags: mysql, node.js

when is start the server and I make some requests to the node the node get the data from MySQL correctly and the connection between the node and the MySQL server seems to be good but after a while, I get the next error why?

this is the code:

```
function handleDisconnect() {
connection = mysql.createConnection(config.get('MySql'));
connection.connect(function (err) {           
    if (err) {                                   
        console.log(dateFormat(new Date(), "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss:l"), get 
           data reconnecting to db:', err);
        setTimeout(handleDisconnect, 2000); 
    } else {
        console.log(dateFormat(new Date(), "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss:l"), 
           "INFO", "Database in get data module is connected ... nn");
    }                                     
});                                     

connection.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('lost db connection in report modules reconnecting');
    if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') { 
        handleDisconnect();                       
    } else {                                      
        throw err;                                 
    }
});

handleDisconnect();
```

and this is the error i get:

```
2018-06-16 22:19:23:985 ERRORE lost connection in get data reconnecting 
to db: { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED *.*.*.*:3306
at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1186:14)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue
  (/home/bla/workspace/bla/Server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
at Protocol.handshake 

 (/home/bla/workspace/bla/Server/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js :52:23)
 at Connection.connect 
         (/home/bla/workspace/bla/Server/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
at Timeout.handleDisconnect [as _onTimeout]     (/home/bla/workspace/bla/Server/routes/getData.js:11:16)
at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)


errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '*.*.*.*',
port: 3306,
fatal: true 
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us more about your architecture? Are you running things in docker?  Im not node expert but as far i can tell you are not closing your connections properly, maybe you exhausted your MySql connection pool

Comment: yes i run this with docker. on ubuntu home server. the ip that i give hem is the public static ip of my home router. what are you suggest me to doo maybe the timeout is to short?

Comment: Your local setup looks fine, ip address is also fine (its better to bind containers to localhost instead of your public ip, and if you need outside access create port forwarding on your networks router). For the other part, connect to MySql server with workbench and monitor number of open connections. MySql has a limit on number of open connections you can run in the same time, if you dont close them properly in some point MySql server will refuse all further connections

Comment: If you can, create a sample project for me to take a look

Comment: thanks it helped me